# Terraform - How to create IAM role for AWS Lambda and deploy both?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-iam

I am learning Terraform. I am trying to create a new Lambda function. And I realized that I also need to create an IAM role. So I am trying to do both using Terraform. But it does not allow me to create the role.

This is my Terraform file

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "eu-west-1"
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "terraform_function_role" {
  name               = "terraform_function_role"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy.AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole.policy}"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "terraform_function" {
  filename         = "terraform_function.zip"
  function_name    = "terraform_function"
  handler          = "index.handler"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.terraform_function_role.id}"
  runtime          = "nodejs8.10"
  source_code_hash = "${filebase64sha256("terraform_function.zip")}"
}
```

This is the error that I am getting

```
Error creating IAM Role terraform_function_role: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource
status code: 400
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should create the assume role policy and not use the managed policy. In the assume role policy (which is used for trust relationship) we don't define Resource. It will look like this: `{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"Service":"lambda.amazonaws.com"},"Action":"sts:AssumeRole"}]}`

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 this would be great as an answer if you want to write it up with a bit more detail?

Answer (score 21):

IAM Role's trust relationship (or assume role policy) defines which resource / service can assume the role. In this, we don't define the Resource field. Hence we can't attach IAM policies or use that policy as is. The correct format for Trust Relationship is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }]
}
```

In this scenario, all Lambda functions in your account can assume this role.

You can refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_manage_modify.html#roles-managingrole-editing-console) AWS link for more examples.

**Edit:** Based on @ydaetskcoR comment, here's a working example:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "eu-west-1"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "AWSLambdaTrustPolicy" {
  statement {
    actions    = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect     = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "terraform_function_role" {
  name               = "terraform_function_role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.AWSLambdaTrustPolicy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "terraform_lambda_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.terraform_function_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "terraform_function" {
  filename         = "terraform_function.zip"
  function_name    = "terraform_function"
  handler          = "index.handler"
  role             = aws_iam_role.terraform_function_role.arn
  runtime          = "nodejs8.10"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("terraform_function.zip")
}
```

The changes from your code include the following:

- Updated aws_iam_policy_document resource for assume role permissions
- Changed aws_iam_role resource to use the above mentioned policy document
- Created aws_iam_role_policy_attachment to attach LambdaBasicExecution policy (which enables logging to CloudWatch)
- Updated aws_lambda_function resource to use IAM Role's ARN instead of Id because Lambda function needs the ARN

Comment: This would be improved if you gave a working example based on the OP's code.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are still in the learning phase, I suggest you move to `terraform 0.12` instead, so you can use things like `templatefile`. therefore you don't need to create `data` objects.

One other thing is to always use the Least Privilege Principle when creating policies, meaning your Resource (Lambda, on this case) will only have access to what it needs. For now, it's only CloudWatch, but in a real world scenario this is very likely not the case.

Back to your question, here's how you can create an IAM Role, an IAM Policy and finally an IAM Policy Attachment (this is the bridge between the policy and the role) as well as the AssumeRolePolicy (this is the trust relationship between the service it's going to use it and the role itself). I have extracted it all into templates for you so it's easier to maintain later on. The gist (for an easier read on the eyes) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/tminussi/a2a4a897cd2377f67f188612cb009944).

```
# iam_role
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_role" {
  name = "iam-role"

  assume_role_policy = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/lambda-base-policy.tpl", {})
}

#content of lambda-base-policy.tpl
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}

#iam_policy
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name = "policy"

  policy = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/cloudwatch-policy.tpl", {})
}

#content of cloudwatch-policy.tpl
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
  ]
} 

#iam_policy_attachment
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "policy_attachment" {
  name       = "attachment"
  roles      = ["${aws_iam_role.iam_role.name}"]
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.policy.arn}"
}
```

Comment: The template isn't doing anything useful here, why not just include it inline?

Comment: It is certainly easier to read templates than putting them inline. Of course this is very basic and is not taking full advantage from injecting variables, etc. Or you truly believe that inline templates are easier to read/maintain?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am still unclear about why I should be using a trust relationship? In other words, when I use aws-cli to deploy a new Lambda function, it creates a role with a managed policy. How do I create that kind managed policy using terraform?

Comment: A trust relationship is needed so a service can assume a role. Imagine that there's a role that you want to be assumed by a Lambda function but never by an EC2 instance, for example. Using the Trust Relationship guarantees it never happens.

Comment: And that role you mention, if you click on it through AWS's console through IAM Roles -> Role -> your_role -> Trust Relationship you will see it can be assumed by Lambda

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, you have to create assume role then attach the assume rule with your newly created policy, here is the complete working example.

```
#assume role
resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
      name = "test-alb-logs-to-elk"
      path = "/"

      assume_role_policy = <<EOF
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Sid": ""
        }
      ]
    }
    EOF
    }

# Created Policy for IAM Role (s3 and log access)
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name = "my-test-policy"
  description = "A test policy"


  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "s3:Get*",
          "s3:List*"
          ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        }
  ]
}
EOF
}

# Attached IAM Role and the new created Policy
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.policy.arn}"
}



# Created AWS Lamdba Function: Memory Size, NodeJS version, handler, endpoint, doctype and environment settings
resource "aws_lambda_function" "elb_logs_to_elasticsearch" {
  function_name = "mytest-alb-logs-to-elk"
  description   = "elb-logs-to-elasticsearch"
  memory_size = 1024
  filename         = "terraform_function.zip"
  runtime          = "nodejs8.10"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.role.arn}"
  handler          = "index.handler"


}
```

Comment: When using aws-cli, it creates a managed policy on it's own. Is there any way to replicate that behavior using terraform? Or is it just recommended to always use assume role policies?

Comment: I was also thinking why not let AWS create the default Role as it does through AWS UI, but here we can see that the Role argument is mandatory hence we have to define it:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function